# How do i create a class with certain rules for creating object?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am a noob working on my very basic hobby program on chemestry, where i have created a class compound and added string **compundname**, but i want to design it in such a way that when i put in some invalid element in compund string, ex- **NaMmO4** the compiler will not let me create object and instead come with an error something like "Mm invalid element"

Note:: my concern here is only with error handling.

example

> compound sodiumsalt {"NMmO4"}

compiler should give error something like -

> Mm is an Invalid element. cannot create object.

Comment: Lookup _templates_ and _type-traits_. For checking string literals that can be only done at runtime (e.g. using regex).

Comment: Compiler will never check your string literal. Use `enum` to represent your elements.

Comment: Seems really bizarre to apply that restriction at compile time, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Using strings, it can't be done at compile-time, it has to be done at run-time. Especially if the strings can be input at run-time.

Comment: @TheDude is there any mechanism to prevent myself from creating some dumb useless objects in c++?

Comment: @user9180468 What do you mean by "dumb useless object"? It's not clear to me exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: _@user9180468_ Lookup the stuff I mentioned in my 1st comment. Also use `enum` isntead of strings to identify chemical elements. @Francois From POV of a _chemist_ obviously.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, the strings will be put by me, i know its useless but i am just wandering in c++ world :)

Comment: OK @TheDude , thanks for info. i love stack overflow community.

Comment: @user9180468 _"compound is clearly not possible"_ For an experienced chemist that's clear, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the job of the compiler and what compiler-errors are.

Compiler errors are mostly sintax error and easy-to-spot running errors, where the compiler doesn't know what are you trying to do. To write the wrong string name will never be a compiler error. Also, it seems the name will be written at running time, which happens after compiler-time.

Might want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std; 
//some people are heavily against it, but I think is easier to use it if you are a beginner. 

enum class elem_t{elem1, elem2, elem3};

class outOfBound: public exception
{
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Error: Accessed an element that doesn't exists.";
    }
} noElem;


class Compound{
public:
    Compound(elem_t* elems, int size){_elems = elems; _size = size;} 
    //can't include something is not part of elem_t

    elem_t operator()(unsigned pos) const {if(pos < _size) return _elems[pos]; else throw noElem;}
    int size() const{return _size;}

private:
    elem_t* _elems;
    int _size;
};

int main()
{
    elem_t a[] = {elem_t::elem2, elem_t::elem1};
    Compound first(a,2);

    return 0;
}
```

The only basic thing I didn't do is a print() or operator<<, but it should be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didnt get everything 100% but what i got helped me, will try implementing similar to this. :)